# concatenate content using loop over array

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have a Bixby capsule in progress that lets users access both free and premium content "packs". Each pack is a file stored in a content/ directory.  I want to loop over these files and read them into a variable called entitled_content.

I started from the facts capsule which uses a utility function to search a local file called content.js.

```
const CONTENT = []
const literature = require("../content/literature")
const enhanced = require("../content/enhanced")
const roosevelt = require("../content/roosevelt")
const ambition = require("../content/ambition")
const chaucer = require ("../content/chaucer")
//const GET_REMOTE = require('./lib/getRemoteContent.js')

var console = require('console')
console.log(roosevelt)
console.log(ambition)
console.log(chaucer)
const entitlements = ["roosevelt", "ambition", "chaucer"]

var entitled_content = []
entitlements.forEach(function (item) { 
  entitled_content = entitled_content.concat(item)
  console.log(item); })

console.log(entitled_content)
```

What it does is this:

```
[ { tags: [ 'roosevelt' ],
    text: 'Happiness is not a goal; it is a by-product. --Eleanor Roosevelt',
    image: { url: 'images/' } } ]
[ { tags: [ 'ambition' ],
    text: 'Ambition is but avarice on stilts, and masked.  --Walter Savage Landor' } ]
[ { tags: [ 'literature' ],
    text: 'A man was reading The Canterbury Tales one Saturday morning, when his wife asked What have you got there?  Replied he, Just my cup and Chaucer.' },
  { tags: [ 'literature' ],
    text: 'For years a secret shame destroyed my peace-- I\'d not read Eliot, Auden or MacNiece. But now I think a thought that brings me hope: Neither had Chaucer, Shakespeare, Milton, Pope. Source: Justin Richardson.' } ]
roosevelt
ambition
chaucer
[ 'roosevelt', 'ambition', 'chaucer' ]
```

What I want it to do is to assemble these three files roosevelt, ambition and chaucer into a single array variable entitled_content that will then be searched by the utility function.  What's wrong is that this line   entitled_content = entitled_content.concat(item) isn't doing what I want it to do, which is to get the entire contents of the file named "item".

Comment: What do you want from it? The text? The tags? the whole thing? Perhaps add an example of what the final item should look like in regard of the example object.

Comment: ```module.exports = [
{tags: ["roosevelt"], text: "Happiness is not a goal; it is a by-product. --Eleanor Roosevelt", image: {url: "images/"}},

{tags: ["ambition"], text: "Ambition is but avarice on stilts, and masked.  --Walter Savage Landor"},

{tags: ["literature"], text: "A man was reading The Canterbury Tales one Saturday morning, when his wife asked What have you got there?  Replied he, Just my cup and Chaucer."}]
```
an array variable

Comment: concatenating the contents of all the entitled packs into a single array that is then searched by a function in util.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you wrapped your variable names in quotation marks the program reads them as strings.

Change it from

`const entitlements = ["roosevelt", "ambition", "chaucer"]`

to

`const entitlements = [roosevelt, ambition, chaucer]`